# Accessing a classes variable in python

Tags: python, class, variables

I understand that this is a duplicate, but I havent had that "ah-ha" moment where I understand HOW to access the a classes variable. In this code, I am crawling a website from a list of thousands of pages. Those jobs are submitted via concurrent.futures.

I want to be able to return the value of "results". I've used `self.results` within `def __init__(self, url_list, threads)` and I cant seem to pull that variable when I try `print(example.results`.

If `self.results` is returning a value, but `example.results` isn't pulling it from `if __name__ == '__main__':`, how can you access that? I know I've done something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from proxy_def import *
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from parsers import *

site = 0


class ConcurrentListCrawler(object):

    def __init__(self, url_list, threads):

        self.urls = url_list
        self.results = {}
        self.max_threads = threads

    def __make_request(self, url):
        try:
            r = requests.get(url=url, timeout=20)
            r.raise_for_status()
            print(countit(), r.url)
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            r = requests.get(url=url, timeout=60)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            r = requests.get(url=url, timeout=60)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            raise e
        return r.url, r.text

    def __parse_results(self, url, html):

        try:
            print(url)
            trip_data = restaurant_parse(url)

        except Exception as e:
            raise e

        if trip_data:
            print('here we go')
            self.results = trip_data
            #print(self.results)
        return self.results


    def wrapper(self, url):
        url, html = self.__make_request(url)
        self.__parse_results(url, html)

    def run_script(self):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=min(len(self.urls),self.max_threads)) as Executor:
            jobs = [Executor.submit(self.wrapper, u) for u in self.urls]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    listo = loadit()
    print(listo)
    print(len(listo))
    example = ConcurrentListCrawler(listo, 10)
    example.run_script()
    print(example.results)
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "self.results isnt working"?  Are you getting an error?  Is the variable empty?  Does it contain unexpected values?

Comment: You call `.run_script()` to launch threads to do your scraping - and then *immediately* try to print `self.results`.  It's unlikely that any thread has completed its job at that point; probably none of them have even started yet.  You also have the issue of all the threads trying to overwrite the single `self.results` variable, rather than appending to it.

Comment: `self.results = trip_data` discards the previous contents of self.results.

Comment: Oh, no I commited the worst dev sin of all time, "not working". What I meant, is that when I call that method and I go to print example.results, nothing prints in the console.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I removed the `self.results = trip data` and still, I can't pull that variable out of the class. I know there is a dictionary assigned there, as I can print it from within the method, but `example.results` when called from `if __name__ == '__main__':` doesn't yield the dictionary.

Comment: That's interesting @jasonharper, I assumed that since it was a different thread, the result wouldn't write over each other.

Comment: _I can't pull that variable out of the class_ I have no idea what that means.  Do you get an exception?  Is the variable empty?

Comment: @JohnGordon, no, there is no exception. self.results is a dictionary and it has exactly what it is supposed to have. However, when I try to access that variable within `if __name__ == '__main__':` by `print(example.results)` nothing prints to the console. However, if I print `self.results` from `def __parse_results`, I can see that there is an assigned variable. That's the troubling part, and the "ah-ha" moment I am missing.

Comment: 1. try returning trip_data directly, without assigning to self.results and let us know if you see any results.<br>

2. use "self.results[url] = trip_data" in stead of self.results = trip_data.

Comment: Do you get output from the other two print statements inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block?

Comment: @JohnGordon, yep, those two print statements will return a valid variable. So all is good there.

Comment: Then it's not possible for `print(example.results)` to output literally nothing.  It has to print _something_, whether it's an empty dictionary, or a blank line, or something similar.

Comment: @murphy1310, ok, I tried both suggestions you put forth, one after the other. `if trip_data: print('here we go') self.results[url] = trip_data return trip_data` Still, I can't return that variable from `__name__ == '__main__'`. This is so weird, it should work!

Comment: @JohnGordon, even if I change `print(example.results)` to `print(example.results, 'print this as well')`, nothing is printed to the console. The only other prints, are those within the method itself, indicating the url it is accessing.

Comment: So, it isnt printing because that line, print(example.results) isnt being executed until all the jobs have been submitted! DUH. So, now I have to figure out how to return that variable from the job itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I submitted all the jobs at once through a list. I was unable to pull the variable from the class because `print(example.results)` because that part of the code isnt access until all jobs are complete. With that I was able to resolve by getting rid of the class (even though the title of this posting indicates that this is the issue).

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import concurrent
from proxy_def import *
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from parsers import *

site = 0

def load_url(url):

    try:
        print(countit(), url)
        trip_data = restaurant_parse(url)
        return trip_data

    except Exception as e:
        raise e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    URLs = loadit()
    #print(URLs)
    #print(len(URLs))
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        # start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url): url for url in URLs}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                data = future.result()
                print('this is data', data)
            except Exception as exc:
                print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
```

Here, I can pull the dictionary by grabbing `data`.

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: you seem to have changed your "question / problem". 

Anyway, whatever suits your solution. (y)

Comment: Yes, @murphy1310, the issue wasn't the class, it was the threading submitting all the jobs and never reaching the print statement until the end. Thanks again for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of your methods is not returning the results. 
Make the following change.

```
def wrapper(self, url):
    url, html = self.__make_request(url)
    return self.__parse_results(url, html)
```

After this, I suggest you utilize the self.results as a dictionary, like it was declared.
In the method "__parse_results(..)", append trip_data to self.results as follows, instead of assigning.

```
def __parse_results(self, url, html):

    try:
        print(url)
        trip_data = restaurant_parse(url)

    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    if trip_data:
        print('here we go')
        self.results[url] = trip_data
        #print(self.results)
    return self.results
```

When you append to self.results, it would retain the older values and you may avoid replacing by reassignment.